# SQL get all rows that satisfy condition 1 when at least one of them also satisfies condition 2

Tags: sql, psql

I have table `A` with `UNIQUE (ID, FK)` combination and `modified` column.

I need to group all entries of table `A` with same `FK` when at least one of those entries match a `CONDITION` based on `modified`.

This is what i am doing right now

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, FK, MAX(modified) 
     FROM A 
     GROUP BY FK) AS A 
WHERE 
    (modified > date1 AND modifed <= date2)
```

Problem is the `CONDITION` gives very less number of records like 1% of the records from `GROUP BY`. I am running `GROUP BY` on whole table unnecessarily

---

Thank you everyone for help, it's because of your efforts i have learned that, although it seems redundant `Grouping everything and then filtering` is the best solution for this situation.

Comment: I don't get what your issue is.  Perhaps if you explained the condition it would help.

Comment: Updated the query, it has the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FK, MAX(modified) m
FROM A 
GROUP BY FK
HAVING (m > date1 AND m <= date2)
```

Here is Postgres analogue

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2230a/6

```
SELECT FK, MAX(modified) AS m
FROM A 
GROUP BY FK
HAVING (MAX(modified) > (now()-INTERVAL '1 DAY') AND MAX(modified) <= now())
```

Comment: That didn't work, i think HAVING uses keys from the original table, as it says column "m" does not exist

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. my code is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2230ab/3

Comment: Hmm, I am using psql I think it might be different for psql. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: This one works but the cost of the query is exactly same as one i am using currently

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the expression using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT FK, MAX(modified)
FROM A
GROUP BY FK
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN modified > date 1 and modifed < date2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

This will not change performance.  For that, use `EXISTS` (or `IN`):

```
select fk, max(modified)
from a
where exists (select 1
              from a a2
              where a2.fk = a.fk and a2.modified > date1 and a2.modified < date2
             )
group by fk;
```

This filters *before* the `group by`, so it should make the aggregation more efficient.  You do want an index on `a(fk, modified)`.

Comment: If i dont have an index on a(fk, modified), will this still be better than what i am using?

Comment: That depends.  You'll need to try it out.  The `join` will be more expensive, but it might save enough on the `group by` to be worth it.

Comment: Ok i have checked it in EXPLAIN, the scenario is (1 record matches the condition out of 5000 and 100 records with same FK) The query i am using costed 250 while this one costed around 310, both gave same result

Comment: HAVING query didn't work directly I had to add SUM() > 0 to make it work and it costed around 270

Comment: @AvcS . . . Without being able to add the right index, there may not be much you can do.

Comment: I have to query from read-only database and i cant create an index, So i think that's the only option. Thank you for help though

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include row in `group by` just use `where` clause before `group by`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, MAX(modified) 
WHERE (modified > date1 OR modifed <= date2)
FROM A 
GROUP BY FK;
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion i have edited the query above, i need a count of all instances of that FK when one of them matches the condition

Comment: @AvcS. . . Include `count()` function and use `OR` instead of `AND`.